# How to delete from state in a deeply nested object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am working on ReactJS with Redux application. I made a change to my state which resulted in an extra layer of properties. So the original state structure was:

```
filters: {
    filterGroupId-1 : {
        id: filterGroupId-1
        selectedFilters: []
    }
    filterGroupId-2 : {
        id: filterGroupId-1
        selectedFilters: []
    }
    filterGroupId-3 : {
        id: filterGroupId-1
        selectedFilters: []
    }
}
```

This has now changed to:

```
filters: {
    dataSource-1: {
        filterGroupId-1 : {
            id: filterGroupId-1
            selectedFilters: []
        }
        filterGroupId-2 : {
            id: filterGroupId-1
            selectedFilters: []
        }
        filterGroupId-3 : {
            id: filterGroupId-1
            selectedFilters: []
        }
    }

    dataSource-2 {
        ...
    }
}
```

To delete a filter group, I originally has the following code in the filters reducer:

```
case FILTER_GROUP_DELETED:
    const { [action.data.filterGroupId]: deletedValue, ...newState } = state;

    return newState
```

What changes to do I need to make to the above snippet to account for the extra layer introduced to the state structure? (filter group objects are now under the data source property)

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract your object from your state, and then apply the exact same method to delete your element, you will then return a JSON object out of your switch and directly use `setState` with it :

```
case FILTER_GROUP_DELETED:
    const { ['dataSource-1']: dataSource } = state;
    const { [action.data.filterGroupId]: deletedValue, ...newSource } = dataSource;

    return { 'dataSource-1':  newSource }
```

Comment: Thanks - took me a while to get my head around it, works now as expected. I had a few issues initially but realised this was because the return statement was overwriting everything - I amended it like so: `return { ...state, 'dataSource-1':  newSource }`